# Magento 1.9 - echo Product Stock Alert next to "Out of Stock" Label

Tags: php, product, magento-1.9

as the title suggests, I'm trying to display the "Sign up to be notified when this product is back in stock" link next to the "Out of Stock" Label.

So it should look like:
[image: Example]

I'm going through all of the templates, and in `template/catalog/product/view.phtml` there is this code snippet:
`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>`, which is from:
`template/productalert/product/view.phtml` (which just contains the code to echo the actual link.) What I would like to do in this template is something like the following, where I have `INSERT STOCK ALERT LINK HERE`:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct() ?>

<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <p class="availability in-stock">
            <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span>
        </p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock">
            <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span>
            <!-- ******* INSERT STOCK ALERT LINK HERE ******* -->
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data_extra') ?>
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
```

I have disabled Price alerts as this is not needed. So the only alert will be the Sign up for stock notification.

I've tried many things, but I think perhaps that it is the scope of the `$this` variable that prevents me from accessing it. Your advice or suggestions are most welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I just came across this page: http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/product-alert-notify-html-in-product-list-view-55751.html, which gives instructions on how to edit the `getSaveURL()` function in the Core file (**yikes!**) `/app/code/core/Mage/ProductAlert/Helper/Data.php` with the following code:

```
public function getSaveUrl($type, $product = null)
{
    if (!empty($product))
    {
        $product_id = $product->getId();
    }
    else
    {
        $product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();
    }

    return $this->_getUrl('productalert/add/' . $type, array(
        'product_id' => $product_id,
        Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->getEncodedUrl()
    ));
}
```

and then to output the link: `<a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('productalert')->getSaveUrl('stock', $_product); ?>">&nbsp;Notify Me When Available</a>` in your phtml.

Now this works well, but I'm a bit hesitant settling on a solution that involves modifying Core files. Is there any way I can make use of the above snippet of code without overriding any core files?